# How do you take a weighted mean where values farther from a given number are weighted less?

Tags: mean

Say, I have a vector v = {5,2,8,9,2}

I then want a weighted mean where values of v closer to a given number (which could be mean(v), or something else) are weighted more (proportionally). So 5 (or v(1)) should be weighted more heavily than 9 (which should be given low weight).

The given number could be the mean, but it could also be any other value. For sake of simplicity though, you can give the answer as if you were giving it for the distance from the mean.

Comment: A working example appears at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/35159, where weights are based on distance in the plane.

Comment: Sorry to ask, but: why was my answer un-accepted?

Answer (score 3):

The mean known as Dodonov's mean seems to fulfill what you are asking for: in this, every data-point is assigned a weight based on the inverse average distance to each of the other data points.

Let $w_i = {{n - 1} \over {\sum^{n}_{j-1}|x_i-x_j|}}$ be the weight for the i'th datapoint. Then the Dodonov-mean is defined as

$\mu_D = {{\sum^n_{n=1}w_ix_i} \over{\sum^n_{n=1}w_i}}$

The paper by the Dodonovs is located [here](http://psystudy.com/files/Dodonov_Dodonova_psystudy_ru_2011_5%2819%29en.pdf).